# Any algorithm for finding Euclidean shortest path with specific constraints in 2D?

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, shortest-path

I have the following problem:

> In a 2D space with polygonal obstacles, find the shortest path between two given point.

Without additional constraints, we can reduce it to a graph problem by constructing a visibility graph and then solve it by searching.

If the following constraints are added, how can we solve it?

Let's define a path as a set of line segments.

1. Each segment must be longer than a given value.
2. Each segment must be horizontal or vertical. (simplified version)
   Each segment must be parallel or perpendicular to other segments. (general version)

**Clarification**

- The problem is in continuous 2D space.
- To simply the problem, the direction of the first and the last segments is given.

**Application**

This can be considered as a routing problem. I am going to use the algorithm for MEP services routing (e.g. duct, pipe, cable tray).

We need a connector to connect two services when the direction is changed.

- As the connector consumes some space, we have constraint (1).
- As we only have limited choices of the connector (90°, 60°, 45°, 30°), we have constraint (2). To simplified the problem, I only use connector for right angle.

Comment: My first reference is http://www.ece.northwestern.edu/~haizhou/357/lec6.pdf
I am thinking about using line search.

Comment: Cool. Thanks. This might be better split into two questions, because I suspect the answer might be quite different for the two problems. Do you have any objection/problem with doing that? Also, now that I see the lecture notes, are you thinking about a discrete 2D grid, or a continuous 2D space? The lecture notes are for a discrete grid. The problem looks quite different in a continuous space.

Comment: It is in continuous 2D space. With the constraint 2, we may construct a grid on the space.     The application is about MEP service routing. I will edit the question to add more detail.

Comment: Thanks.  An edit would be great.  For constraint 2, it's still not clear to me how you construct a grid: What is the grid spacing?  (You haven't restricted segments to have a length that is a multiple of some unit length.)  Also, it's not clear what angle the grid should be at.  (You haven't specified the angle, so presumably each possible angle yields a possible grid.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12383/discussion-between-tatepoon-and-d-w)